# How to parse recipes ingredient line using coldfusion?

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion

I am using JSOUP(http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML page and extract the data from that page. In that, i am extracting recipes details like its cooking time, instructions & ingredients. Take all this data from HTML page and saved it in archive table named recipeImport.

Before inserting these to a valid recipes table. I have to parse the ingredients because it has been stored in the recipe_ingredient table based three different master tables namely recipeAmount, recipeUnitType & recipeIngredient.

Let me consider a simple ingredient like "1 cup white sugar". I've separate the amount(1), unitType(cup) and ingredient(sugar) to match with these(recipeAmount, recipeUnitType & recipeIngredient) master table and insert the ingredient in recipe_ingredient table with the reference ID'S.

recipeAmount table

```
ID amountType amountTypeValue
1       1/2         0.5
2       1           1
```

recipeUnitType Table

```
ID UnitType
1   cup
2   tbs
3   tsp
4   gram
```

recipeIngredient table

```
ID  ingredientName 

1      sugar
2      salt
3      Honey
```

Finally, I have to save the ingredient like this.

recipe_ingredient table

```
ID   amountID   unitTypeID   ingredientID   line_text       ingredient_line

1      2            1             1          white Sugar    1 cup white sugar
```

So Far I have used this regular expression to check the valid ingredient.

```
regex1 = "^((\d+)|(\d+\/\d+)|(\d+)\s(\d+\/\d+)|(\d+-\d+))\s((dash|pinch|tsp|tbs|fl oz|cup|pt|qt|gal|oz|lb|cl|can)|(dash|pinch|teaspoon|tablespoon|fluid ounce|cup|pint|quart|gallon|ounce|pound|fresh|clove|small|medium|large|slice|hand|of|turnip))(s)?\b\s[A-Za-z0-9(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+[A-Za-z(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+$";

regex2 = "^((\d+)|(\d+.\d+))\s((kg|g|lb|cl)|(kilo gram|gram|pound))(s)?\b\s[A-Za-z0-9(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+[A-Za-z(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+$";

regex3 = "^((a|an|extra))\s[A-Za-z0-9(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+[A-Za-z(,|\-|&|:|!|" & "'|" & '"' & ")\s]+$";
```

Comment: Please share some code, that shows what have you already tried

Comment: @LukasKabrt So far I've used regular expression to check the format.

Comment: What exactly is your question? @Dineshkumar